# How to config sublimelinter icon?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimelinter

In sublime text 3, when a code line is marked by `sublimelinter` and then add a bookmark, the "linter icon" will be override by the "bookmark icon"(line `473`), will there's some configuration to fix it?

line 473 is marked by sublimelinter and then I add a bookmark

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 3 currently only displays one icon in the gutter per line - so currently it is not possible to fix it via any means. https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/319